# Windows Form - Make "User Control" Drag-Drop Capable

Tags: winforms, drag-and-drop, user-controls

I want to make my windows user control drag-drop capable. I will drag my user control to some other place to drop there.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things we need to do.

1. Make user control (also for any control) draggable.
2. Make some area of form droppable.

**Make draggable:**

Think "Ctrl" is your user control and "ctrl" is an instance of your user control.

- add an event handler :

```
ctrl.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.ctrl_MouseDown);
```

```
 - make draggable:
  private void ctrl_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            ((Ctrl)sender).DoDragDrop("Your data, you want to pass", DragDropEffects.Move);
        }
```

**Make some form area droppable:**

Think "ctlPanel" is a panel of your form, where you want to drop the draggable control. Allow Drop and Assign two events (DragEnter and DragDrop) and handle as below:

- Go to the property of panel and make true of "AllowDrop"
  [image: AllowDrop Property]

```
 private void ctlPanel_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
        }

        private void ctlPanel_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            string  xyz = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.StringFormat) as string;
        }
```

That's all.